# How do I update my Arch system without replacing these packages?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro

When I run `sudo pacman -Syu`, it asks me if i want to replace these packages one by one. I tried `--noconfirm` flag but it is not working. How can I update my system without updating these packages?

```shellsession
$ sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace karchive with extra/karchive5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kauth with extra/kauth5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kbookmarks with extra/kbookmarks5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kcmutils with extra/kcmutils5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kcodecs with extra/kcodecs5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kcompletion with extra/kcompletion5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kconfig with extra/kconfig5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kconfigwidgets with extra/kconfigwidgets5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kcontacts with extra/kcontacts5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kcoreaddons with extra/kcoreaddons5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kcrash with extra/kcrash5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kdbusaddons with extra/kdbusaddons5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kdeclarative with extra/kdeclarative5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kded with extra/kded5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kglobalaccel with extra/kglobalaccel5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kguiaddons with extra/kguiaddons5? [Y/n]
:: Replace ki18n with extra/ki18n5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kiconthemes with extra/kiconthemes5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kio with extra/kio5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kirigami-addons with extra/kirigami-addons5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kitemmodels with extra/kitemmodels5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kitemviews with extra/kitemviews5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kjobwidgets with extra/kjobwidgets5? [Y/n]
:: Replace knotifications with extra/knotifications5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kpackage with extra/kpackage5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kpeople with extra/kpeople5? [Y/n]
warning: kpeoplevcard: local (0.1+r38.32d50a9-1) is newer than extra (0.1-2)
:: Replace kservice with extra/kservice5? [Y/n]
:: Replace ktextwidgets with extra/ktextwidgets5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kwallet with extra/kwallet5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kwidgetsaddons with extra/kwidgetsaddons5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kwindowsystem with extra/kwindowsystem5? [Y/n]
:: Replace kxmlgui with extra/kxmlgui5? [Y/n]
:: Replace modemmanager-qt with extra/modemmanager-qt5? [Y/n]
:: Replace qqc2-desktop-style with extra/qqc2-desktop-style5? [Y/n]
:: Replace solid with extra/solid5? [Y/n]
:: Replace sonnet with extra/sonnet5? [Y/n]
resolving dependencies...
:: There are 128 providers available for tessdata:
:: Repository extra
   1) tesseract-data-afr  2) tesseract-data-amh  3) tesseract-data-ara  4) tesseract-data-asm  5) tesseract-data-aze
   6) tesseract-data-aze_cyrl  7) tesseract-data-bel  8) tesseract-data-ben  9) tesseract-data-bod  10) tesseract-data-bos
   11) tesseract-data-bre  12) tesseract-data-bul  13) tesseract-data-cat  14) tesseract-data-ceb  15) tesseract-data-ces
   16) tesseract-data-chi_sim  17) tesseract-data-chi_sim_vert  18) tesseract-data-chi_tra  19) tesseract-data-chi_tra_vert
   20) tesseract-data-chr  21) tesseract-data-cos  22) tesseract-data-cym  23) tesseract-data-dan
   24) tesseract-data-dan_frak  25) tesseract-data-deu  26) tesseract-data-deu_frak  27) tesseract-data-div
   28) tesseract-data-dzo  29) tesseract-data-ell  30) tesseract-data-eng  31) tesseract-data-enm  32) tesseract-data-epo
   33) tesseract-data-equ  34) tesseract-data-est  35) tesseract-data-eus  36) tesseract-data-fao  37) tesseract-data-fas
   38) tesseract-data-fil  39) tesseract-data-fin  40) tesseract-data-fra  41) tesseract-data-frk  42) tesseract-data-frm
   43) tesseract-data-fry  44) tesseract-data-gla  45) tesseract-data-gle  46) tesseract-data-glg  47) tesseract-data-grc
   48) tesseract-data-guj  49) tesseract-data-hat  50) tesseract-data-heb  51) tesseract-data-hin  52) tesseract-data-hrv
   53) tesseract-data-hun  54) tesseract-data-hye  55) tesseract-data-iku  56) tesseract-data-ind  57) tesseract-data-isl
   58) tesseract-data-ita  59) tesseract-data-ita_old  60) tesseract-data-jav  61) tesseract-data-jpn
   62) tesseract-data-jpn_vert  63) tesseract-data-kan  64) tesseract-data-kat  65) tesseract-data-kat_old
   66) tesseract-data-kaz  67) tesseract-data-khm  68) tesseract-data-kir  69) tesseract-data-kmr  70) tesseract-data-kor
   71) tesseract-data-kor_vert  72) tesseract-data-lao  73) tesseract-data-lat  74) tesseract-data-lav
   75) tesseract-data-lit  76) tesseract-data-ltz  77) tesseract-data-mal  78) tesseract-data-mar  79) tesseract-data-mkd
   80) tesseract-data-mlt  81) tesseract-data-mon  82) tesseract-data-mri  83) tesseract-data-msa  84) tesseract-data-mya
   85) tesseract-data-nep  86) tesseract-data-nld  87) tesseract-data-nor  88) tesseract-data-oci  89) tesseract-data-ori
   90) tesseract-data-pan  91) tesseract-data-pol  92) tesseract-data-por  93) tesseract-data-pus  94) tesseract-data-que
   95) tesseract-data-ron  96) tesseract-data-rus  97) tesseract-data-san  98) tesseract-data-sin  99) tesseract-data-slk
   100) tesseract-data-slk_frak  101) tesseract-data-slv  102) tesseract-data-snd  103) tesseract-data-spa
   104) tesseract-data-spa_old  105) tesseract-data-sqi  106) tesseract-data-srp  107) tesseract-data-srp_latn
   108) tesseract-data-sun  109) tesseract-data-swa  110) tesseract-data-swe  111) tesseract-data-syr
   112) tesseract-data-tam  113) tesseract-data-tat  114) tesseract-data-tel  115) tesseract-data-tgk
   116) tesseract-data-tgl  117) tesseract-data-tha  118) tesseract-data-tir  119) tesseract-data-ton
   120) tesseract-data-tur  121) tesseract-data-uig  122) tesseract-data-ukr  123) tesseract-data-urd
   124) tesseract-data-uzb  125) tesseract-data-uzb_cyrl  126) tesseract-data-vie  127) tesseract-data-yid
   128) tesseract-data-yor

Enter a number (default=1):
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing kpeople breaks dependency 'kpeople' required by kpeoplevcard
:: removing kcontacts breaks dependency 'kcontacts' required by kpeoplevcard
```

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea, and that's probably why tooling for doing that is not very comfortable. How do you ensure that you don't upgrade any of the dependencies of these packages you hold back? I thought Arch had no notion of dependency versioning!

Comment: Is there a fix for this? I do not want to upgrade all packages as I am fully aware it is likely to break my system. [read](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236186)

Comment: Yes. Don't use a Linux distro that requires all packages to be updated at the same time. I think Arch might be a nice distro for many things, but it's the wrong tool for your use

Comment: How about you try to understand what `pacman` is telling you and temporarily remove `kpeoplevcard` and let KDE update itself while not in KDE.  Don't worry about broken packages because the update will reinstall them in the proper order.  You're asking us to resolve a circular dependency.  If the package manager can't figure it out, neither can we, and set the proper variable for tesseract to pull in only your language.

Comment: See the [Teseract OCR Documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html) to figure out how to install the proper language.

Comment: There is some useful information about this here https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/arch-package-name-changes/31668  You probably do want to switch to the versions with a 5 at the end. A useful technique for solving Pac-Man issues is to identify the problem packages and set them to be skipped. That way you can get most of the upgrade done. Then unskip the problem packages and more often than not they install correctly. I’ve gone through all of this and my system is fine.